# Can enter new line into PHP ajax and cant request intended date into the sendRequest() method

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, line-breaks, fwrite

```
<?php
$myFile = "Wishes.txt";

$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$mystring= $_POST["name"];
fwrite($fh, $mystring."\n\r");
fclose($fh);
?>  

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                <title>Wish well</title>
                <script language="javascript">

                        function sendtoajax(form)
                        {
                                var xmlhttp;
                                var content;
                                content=form.wish.value;

                                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                                  {
                                  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                                  {
                                alert('done')
                                 }
                                }
                                xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax.php",true);
                                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                                xmlhttp.send("form.text.value");
                        }
                </script>
        </head>
        <body style="background-color:red;">

                <form name="Text">
                            Text<input type="text" name="text"/>
                            <input type="button" class="button" value="Throw In" onclick="sendtoajax(this.form)"/>
                            <input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
                </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

So I was trying to enter the text input into a text field and submit it into a text file but I encountered 2 major problems ... It always seems to rewrite the previous input so I stays at the first line, would be the first problem and the second one is that 
when I send xmlhttp.send("form.text.value"); request it sends over null, instead when I use xmlhttp.send("name=whatever");it writes whatever into the textfile but I cant make it to print the value in the form

Comment: Okay so I solved the append issue by just replacing the "w" with "a" in the 
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file"); line of the php code

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                <title>Wish well</title>
                <script language="javascript">

                        function sendtoajax()
                        {
                                var xmlhttp;
                                var content ="name="+document.getElementById("1111").value;
                                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                                {
                                          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                                          {
                                                alert(content)
                                          }
                                }    
                                xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax.php",true);
                                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                                xmlhttp.send(content);
                        }
                </script>
        </head>
        <body style="background-color:red;">

                I was just thinking that I could do us a private lil webpage ^^ I love you so much hun! <3

                <form name="Wish">
                            Wish<input type="text" name="wish" id="1111"/>
                            <input type="button" class="button" value="Throw In" onclick="sendtoajax()"/>
                            <input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
                </form>
        </body>
</html>

<?php
$myFile = "Wishes.txt";

$mystring= $_POST["name"];
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh,  $mystring."\n");

fclose($fh);
?>
```

So I solved it completely by changing w to a when opening the file in php and the input of the PHP by changing the output of the JS code var content ="name="+document.getElementById("1111").value; which made it comply with the "name" requirement of the POST in PHP. now it does exactly what I intended,I hope it'll help someone else too :)